# When using a ARIMA in python, and have a garde of integration how do you get the forecast to be not integrated?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

So I am using an ARIMA(2,1,1)

```
 model = ARIMA(value, order=(2, 1, 1))
 results = model.fit()
 model_fit = model.fit()

 predict=model_fit.predict(start=1, end=120, exog=None)
 data = pd.DataFrame(data = predict)
 print(data)

 results.plot_predict(95,115)
```

The printed data has the grade of integration how do I get that my values are the actual values?

The real values shows be somehtin along 18000
and I am getting -201, 75 or things like that and if I change the ARIMA to ARIMA(2,0,1) I get the normal values.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Did you check whether your data is stationary or not by performing various test to determine trend and seasonality?

Comment: Yes actually I used a function I created to determine which is the best posible ARIMA and it was the (2,1,1) in this case

Comment: I will suggest you to always check whether there is trend/seasonality or not and carry out some transformation to make it stationary and determine p,d,q. The function you created to determine will only give you rough idea.

Comment: Okey I understand what you are trying to say and thus appreciate the help. But wheter I do have a trend and my series is not stationary and I will need a d=1,2..etc. Then my question is still the same. But also again Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having a differenced time-series and you want to undifference the output.

```
 predict=model_fit.predict(start=1, end=120, exog=None, typ ='levels' )
```

That should do the trick

```
typ = 'levels'
```

converts the differenced data to undifferenced data